# Display a new render object in Qualcomm's Vuforia for iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, augmented-reality

I grabbed the "ImageTargets" example from the download of Qualcomm's Augmented Reality and I'm trying to display my own 3D render which is already a .h this is my code:

```
 // Draw object
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, [thisTexture textureID]);
            glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, (const GLvoid*)&santtandersupermanTexCoords[0]);
            glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, (const GLvoid*) &santtandersupermanVerts[0]);
            glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, (const GLvoid*)&santtandersupermanNormals[0]);
            //glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, NUM_TEAPOT_OBJECT_INDEX, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (const GLvoid*)&teapotIndices[0]);
            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, GL_FLOAT, (const GLfloat*)&santtandersupermanVerts[0]);
```

The thing is, even though it's not crashing, it's not displaying I get the following error:

> glError (0x500)after EAGLView renderFrameQCAR()

any idea what I could do?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because your data in 'santtandersuperman' doesn't match the expectations you've set with your code.

In particular you've passed verts into glDrawElements which expects an array of indices (and the quantity you've specified is zero).

You should be using:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);
```